# Integrating apache camel with CXf in tomcat

Tags: spring, web-services, apache, tomcat, cxf

Since last few days I'm trying to integrate apache camel with cxf and trying to deploy it in tomcat server.After running throgh maven build becomes successfuly , & when i deploy it into tomcat server, it is always giving me some kinds of version compatablity issues. 
when i run with camel 2.10.4  and CXF 2.7.7, the localhost logs in tomcat says  Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.apache.cxf.jaxws.support.JaxWsServiceFactoryBean.setMethodDispatcher(Lorg/apache/cxf/frontend/MethodDispatcher .

I could not find exactly what is the problem with this. Is this any cxf and camle incompatible version problem or any thing dependency issue.

Please help me in this context.

Here is the localhost log:

```
SEVERE: Exception sending context initialized event to listener instance of class org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'LocationService': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.apache.cxf.jaxws.support.JaxWsServiceFactoryBean.setMethodDispatcher(Lorg/apache/cxf/frontend/MethodDispatcher;)V
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1422)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:518)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:455)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:293)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:222)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:290)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:192)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:585)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:895)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:425)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.createWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:282)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:204)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(ContextLoaderListener.java:47)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:4206)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.start(StandardContext.java:4705)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:799)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:779)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:601)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployWAR(HostConfig.java:943)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployWARs(HostConfig.java:778)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployApps(HostConfig.java:504)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.start(HostConfig.java:1317)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.lifecycleEvent(HostConfig.java:324)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleSupport.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleSupport.java:142)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.start(ContainerBase.java:1065)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.start(StandardHost.java:840)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.start(ContainerBase.java:1057)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine.start(StandardEngine.java:463)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.start(StandardService.java:525)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.start(StandardServer.java:754)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.start(Catalina.java:595)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.start(Bootstrap.java:289)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:414)
Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.apache.cxf.jaxws.support.JaxWsServiceFactoryBean.setMethodDispatcher(Lorg/apache/cxf/frontend/MethodDispatcher;)V
    at org.apache.cxf.jaxws.support.JaxWsServiceFactoryBean.initConfiguration(JaxWsServiceFactoryBean.java:421)
    at org.apache.cxf.jaxws.support.JaxWsServiceFactoryBean.setJaxWsImplementorInfo(JaxWsServiceFactoryBean.java:398)
    at org.apache.cxf.jaxws.support.JaxWsServiceFactoryBean.setServiceClass(JaxWsServiceFactoryBean.java:173)
    at org.apache.cxf.frontend.AbstractWSDLBasedEndpointFactory.initializeServiceFactory(AbstractWSDLBasedEndpointFactory.java:227)
    at org.apache.cxf.frontend.ServerFactoryBean.initializeServiceFactory(ServerFactoryBean.java:157)
    at org.apache.cxf.frontend.AbstractWSDLBasedEndpointFactory.createEndpoint(AbstractWSDLBasedEndpointFactory.java:99)
    at org.apache.cxf.frontend.ServerFactoryBean.create(ServerFactoryBean.java:117)
    at org.apache.cxf.jaxws.JaxWsServerFactoryBean.create(JaxWsServerFactoryBean.java:167)
    at org.apache.cxf.jaxws.EndpointImpl.getServer(EndpointImpl.java:346)
    at org.apache.cxf.jaxws.EndpointImpl.doPublish(EndpointImpl.java:259)
    at org.apache.cxf.jaxws.EndpointImpl.publish(EndpointImpl.java:209)
    at org.apache.cxf.jaxws.EndpointImpl.publish(EndpointImpl.java:404)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeCustomInitMethod(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1546)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1487)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1419)
    ... 36 more
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is cxf version related error. Use cxf version 2.6.0. It might solve your problem. Hope this helps

Comment: Yes that't true it was resolved by updating the verson.